# missing specflow templates in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, specflow

I'm new to BDD and Specflow so please help. Today I installed Specflow V1.8.1 on my local machine. During the installation, I made sure that I chose both VS 2008 and 2010 addon. after installation, I can find the new templates such as .feature in VS 2010, but in VS 2008, I can't finds any of the specflow templates, I tried to reinstall for several times, closing all the VS projects, but things didn't get better. What could be the possible cause? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I've just run into the same problem as I've had to downgrade to VS2008 for a project.  The 1.8.1 installation program works fine for VS2010 but not for VS2008.

**UPDATE**
After installing Specflow installer you'll probably find 3 new specflow*.zip files in the following directory:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp

If you create the sub folder structure **Specflow\1033** and move the following three files into the new 1033 folder:

- SpecFlowEventDefinition.zip
- SpecFlowFeature.zip
- SpecFlowStepDefinition.zip

You can now recreate the item cache using the steps:

1. Open a VS2008 cmd window (under Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 | visual studio tools in start menu) - make sure you run as administrator for this.
2. In the DOS window, enter devenv.exe /installvstemplates and run

**OTHER METHOD**

The following steps could solve the issue for you:

1. Close all VS2008 instances.
2. Copy the non _VB.* files from **C:\Program Files (x86)\TechTalk\SpecFlow\ItemTemplates** to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\SpecFlow\1033**
3. Open a VS2008 cmd window (under Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 | visual studio tools in start menu) - make sure you run as administrator for this.
4. In the DOS window, enter **devenv.exe /installvstemplates** and run.
5. Close the DOS window.
6. Open VS2008 and the items are now available under "Add New" - the options will appear under the top level item "Visual C# Items", they don't appear in any of the child folders.

*Note: Step 2 places the templates in the VS install location, whilst step 4 rebuilds the templates and installs them into the cache (here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\SpecFlow\1033)*

Comment: I had to put the .zip files in the CSharp\1033 folder that was already existing in my case.

Comment: After following the steps above, it appears that you can't have SpecFlow items in smart device projects.